# Display the result of a function in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

In the index function of my controller I am calling getDirContents and I need to display the result of $data['arrDirContents'] in view

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->accesscontrol->can_or_redirect('view', 'translation');
        $dir = './application/language/english';
        $data['arrDirContents']=$this->getDirContents($dir, "~^.+_lang\.php$~i");
        $this->output->view('translation/language',$data);
    }
```

Any help on how to get the result of that function in view?

Comment: Have you written your own "output" class? I would expect to see `$this->load->view('translation/language',$data);` instead of what you show.

Comment: Show the related part of the view file too please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php 
$dir = './application/language/english';
$data['arrDirContents']=$this->getDirContents($dir, "~^.+_lang\.php$~i");
?>`

If this values contents single value means

In View Page just do echo

```
<?php echo $arrDirContents; ?>
```

If this values contents multiple value having array value 
Do foreach print each variable value

```
<?php
foreach( $arrDirContents as $directs):
    echo $directs;
endforech;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->vars( array(
   'arrDirContents'=>$this->getDirContents($dir, "~^.+_lang\.php$~i")
));
```